# Forwarding Traffic from Linux Debian Server to DynIP Windows HomeServer

Tags: linux, networking, debian, proxy

First of all, I was trying and searching for a while now.

I got a **Windows Homeserver** and my **IP is non-static**.

I'm registered @ noip.com and have a CNAME '**example.dyndns.net**' as my connection to the server.
Above that I'm using another domain '**example.de**', redirecting to example.dyndns.net.

So, now I'm beeing **DDOS attacked on my Homeserver** (he got my IP through the public Teamspeak Server) and I still got an old (rent) **Linux Debian vPS with a static IP and full DDOS protection**.

What i want now, is to **forward all traffic through the vPS like a reverse Proxy to my Homeserver**, so it is DDOS protected.

I already tried nginx & apache **reverse proxy**, problem with this: I (guess) cant reverse UDP and TCP packages with this method.

Next thing i tried were **IP-Tables**, which I just can't get working, because of the DynIP/Hostnames resolving.(Googled and tryharded veeery very much around that!)

I'm hoping someone can either help me, or say it's not possible so I can stop trying :)

(Sorry for the German-English ;D )

*EDIT: MOVED FROM STACKOVERFLOW BECAUSE THERE IT WAS OFF-TOPIC*

Comment: Use vpn, especially `openvpn`. Then you can easily forward/route what you want.

Comment: Or Wireguard if your VPS provider supports it (It's in the debian stretch repos) and port forward behind the Wiregaurd interface on the VPS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to setup a Layer2 (or *bridged*) OpenVPN between your Home and your VPS. You can find instructions on how to do that [on the Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openvpn.html), make sure you read the *Advanced bridged VPN configuration on server* which discusses the *layer 2, bridged* configuration (as opposed to the Layer 3 routed configuration). The Debian Wiki does not have this section, which is why I preferred the Ubuntu wiki (rather unusual, for me).

The cute thing of this configuration is that your home client will be given an IP number in the same subnet as your VPS; so, if your VPS has an internal IP address like `10.0.0.1/24`, your home machine will be given an IP number in the same subnet. In this case, in order to allow people querying your VPS for Web pages to load them from your home machine, all you have to do is to use *DNAT* on the VPS:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d Your.External.IP -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to Your.Home.Private.IP.on.theOpenVPN
```

However, you might wish to consider a different course of action: you might move all of your Web server onto the VPS, keeping **the** original copy on your home server, then using *rsync* to update the content every five minutes or so, which is what I do with my Web server. This makes sense if your Web server does not contain anything that requires real-time interaction with users (I host written content, a blog, a mirror site for 3 Unix distros, the weather page of my meteorological station, as an example). It automatically keeps a backup copy of your stuff, should the attacker succeed, and it cleanly isolates the VPS from your home, in that communication would be one-way only, in this case.

Lastly, if push comes to shove, this configuration allows you to use the [blackhole routing defense against DDoS attacks](http://bencane.com/2013/01/14/mitigating-dos-attacks-with-a-null-or-blackhole-route-on-linux/) at home, which you can disable before *rsync*'ing to your VPS and re-enable it as soon as you are done.